# Locating a specific string in a column between two strings which are not always there?

Tags: php, mysql, contao

Long story short, let's assume I have a field in a column called 'whyisthisalist' from 'table' which contains:

```
{example1:"hereistext";example2:"ohlookmoretext";example3:"isthisevenreal"}
```

How would I extract the text between example1 and example2, given that example2 isn't always there because it could also look like this:

```
{example1:"hereistext";example7:"ohlookmoretext"}
```

It should return "hereistext" if everything goes well.

My idea so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(whyisthisalist, LOCATE('\";', whyisthisalist) +0), LOCATE('example1:\"', whyisthisalist) +0, 100)
FROM table
WHERE LOCATE('\";', whyisthisalist) > 0
AND LOCATE('example1:\"', whyisthisalist) > 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

What needs to be done/doesn't work:
I need to get the NEXT occuring "; AFTER the previous located string. Is this even possible? Or is there any other workaround? I'd be glad about some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will get you everything from the first colon to the first semi-colon:

```
\:([^;]*)
```

Simplifying your query like this:

```
SELECT `whyisthisalist` REGEXP '\:([^;]*)'
FROM `table`
```

[MySQL REGEX docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)
[MySQL Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

You can also use [lookahead's and lookbehind's](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) for the regex:

```
(?<=example1:)(.+?)(?=\;)
```